# Javascript, Time and Date: Getting the current minute, hour, day, week, month, year of a given millisecond time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm still wrapping my head around this library, but I'm out of time so I'll just skip to the spoiler section and ask.  With a given, arbitrary millisecond time value (like the kind you'd gave from `.getTime()`), how do I get the current minute, hour, day, week of the month, month, week of the year, and year of that specific millisecond of time?

Additionally, how do I retrieve the number of days of a given month?  Anything I should know about regarding leap years and other stuff?

Comment: It's all explained in the spec. There is a section which describes the date methods, and even the abstract algorithms.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The variable names should be descriptive:

```
var date = new Date;
date.setTime(result_from_Date_getTime);

var seconds = date.getSeconds();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var hour = date.getHours();

var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth(); // beware: January = 0; February = 1, etc.
var day = date.getDate();

var dayOfWeek = date.getDay(); // Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, etc.
var milliSeconds = date.getMilliseconds();
```

The days of a given month do not change. In a leap year, February has 29 days. Inspired by http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/05/24/how-to-know-if-its-a-leap-year/ (thanks Peter Bailey!)

Continued from the previous code:

```
var days_in_months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
// for leap years, February has 29 days. Check whether
// February, the 29th exists for the given year
if( (new Date(year, 1, 29)).getDate() == 29 ) days_in_month[1] = 29;
```

There is no straightforward way to get the week of a year. For the answer on that question, see [Is there a way in javascript to create a date object using year & ISO week number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815514/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-create-a-date-object-using-year-iso-week-number/2815686#2815686)

Comment: The idea's right, I think the logic is a bit off though... maybe `year%400===0 || (year%4===0 && year%100!==0)`.

Comment: This approach is pretty straightforward, too http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/05/24/how-to-know-if-its-a-leap-year/

Comment: Thanks again bobince. I'm using the approach from Peter Bailey now. Great idea. I always forget about such possibilities.

Comment: whats result_from_Date_getTime and why didn't you just call getTime in your example

Answer (score 39):

Here is another method to get date

```
new Date().getDate()          // Get the day as a number (1-31)
new Date().getDay()           // Get the weekday as a number (0-6)
new Date().getFullYear()      // Get the four digit year (yyyy)
new Date().getHours()         // Get the hour (0-23)
new Date().getMilliseconds()  // Get the milliseconds (0-999)
new Date().getMinutes()       // Get the minutes (0-59)
new Date().getMonth()         // Get the month (0-11)
new Date().getSeconds()       // Get the seconds (0-59)
new Date().getTime()          // Get the time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970)
```

Comment: You should ALWAYS take a local copy of the date before extracting values from it as there is a significant chance that each `newDate()` will be returning a slightly different date/time and you could end up with unexpected results.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding number of days in month just use static switch command and check `if (year % 4 == 0)` in which case February will have 29 days.

Minute, hour, day etc:

```
var someMillisecondValue = 511111222127;
var date = new Date(someMillisecondValue);
var minute = date.getMinutes();
var hour = date.getHours();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();
alert([minute, hour, day, month, year].join("\n"));
```

Comment: To check for a leap year you must check `if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))`. This is the definition of the Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, how do I retrieve the number of days of a given month?

Aside from calculating it yourself (and consequently having to get leap years right), you can use a Date calculation to do it:

```
var y= 2010, m= 11;            // December 2010 - trap: months are 0-based in JS

var next= Date.UTC(y, m+1);    // timestamp of beginning of following month
var end= new Date(next-1);     // date for last second of this month
var lastday= end.getUTCDate(); // 31
```

In general for timestamp/date calculations I'd recommend using the UTC-based methods of Date, like `getUTCSeconds` instead of `getSeconds()`, and `Date.UTC` to get a timestamp from a UTC date, rather than `new Date(y, m)`, so you don't have to worry about the possibility of weird time discontinuities where timezone rules change.

Comment: UTC works even when the month goes past december (12 and up)?

Comment: Yes, that works in UTC or local time. (Well, unless in local time there is a timezone change on 1st January, in which case local time could go wrong. I don't know of any locales where that has ever happened, but I've learned always to be suspicious of the weird stuff that local timezone rules can generate...)