# I don't understand how to get Time zone Offset to hide field during closing hours using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, timezone-offset

I am trying to hide a certain field on my website between the hours of 6 pm and 7 am and I was able to find a javascript that could solve that issue for me but the javascript came with `getTimezoneOffset` which is set to `60000` and `3600000*offset` which I do not understand.

My time zone is (UTC + 01:00) West Central Africa.

In the javascript, I set the hours in which the field should be hidden to `16 = 4 pm` and `7 am`

That is `if (hour >= 16 || hour <= 7 {` but it isn't working and I will like some help to fix or understand this problem.

**See code sample below, thank you.**

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //give the offset of your city
    var offset = +1;
    
    // create Date object for current location
    var d = new Date();
    // convert to msec
    // subtract local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    // return "The local time for city"+ city +" is "+ nd.toLocaleString() + "and time is "+nd.toLocaleTimeString() + " hour is "+nd.getHours();
  var hour = nd.getHours();
  
  console.log(hour);
       if (hour >= 16 || hour <= 7 { 
            $("#daniel").hide();
       } else {
                    $("#daniel").show();
       }
    });
    
</script>
```

```html
<input id='daniel' placeholde='tunde' >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your old code is commented and I have added the changes necessary.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    /*//give the offset of your city
    var offset = +1;
    
    // create Date object for current location
    var d = new Date();
    // convert to msec
    // subtract local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    // return "The local time for city"+ city +" is "+ nd.toLocaleString() + "and time is "+nd.toLocaleTimeString() + " hour is "+nd.getHours();
  var hour = nd.getHours();*/
  
  // get browser's current hour
  let hour = new Date().getHours();
  
  // output the variable hour
  console.log(`Current hour: ${hour}`);
  
  // check if the variable hour is between 16 in the afternoon and 7 in the morning
   if ((hour >= 16 && hour <= 23) || (hour >= 0 && hour <= 7)) { 
      console.log("Yes, current browser's hour is between 16 in the afternoon and 7 in the morning");
      $("#daniel").hide();
   } else {
      console.log("No, the browser's time is not between 16 in the afternoon and 7 in the morning")
      $("#daniel").show();
   }
  });
    
</script>
```

EDIT: Make sure to check if hours are between 16 and 23 inclusive or 0 to 7 inclusive because the hours function return 0 to 23. [Check the docs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

`if ((hour >= 16 && hour <= 23) || (hour >= 0 && hour <= 7))`

---

Why don't you just get the current hour directly and check if its between 16 and 7 ?

It's as simple as `new Date().getHours()`

Possible duplicate [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402934/javascript-time-and-date-getting-the-current-minute-hour-day-week-month-y)

Comment: The Possible duplicate solution that you suggested just confused me the more. but thanks for your help. Codinggwiz

Comment: Javascript runs on the client browser so there is no need to check for a specific timezone. When the code returns a time, it returns the current time of the client browser. You then simply check if the returned time is between 16 and 7.

Comment: I humbly ask that you please help to apply your solution to my code above. I am confused because I don't have a full understanding of how this works...I have been studying different javascript solutions for a while now and I just keep geting more confused. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The above code was working for me. I just corrected the typo error (added closing bracket for if condition)

`if (hour >= 16 || hour <= 7 {`
to
`if (hour >= 16 || hour <= 7) {`

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //give the offset of your city
    var offset = +1;

    // create Date object for current location
    var d = new Date();
    // convert to msec
    // subtract local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    var utc = d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    var nd = new Date(utc + 3600000 * offset);

    // return time as a string
    // return "The local time for city"+ city +" is "+ nd.toLocaleString() + "and time is "+nd.toLocaleTimeString() + " hour is "+nd.getHours();
    var hour = nd.getHours();

    console.log(hour);
    if (hour >= 16 || hour <= 7) {
      $("#daniel").hide();
    } else {
      $("#daniel").show();
    }
  });
</script>
<input id="daniel" placeholde="tunde" />
```